# Ajax to working

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following java script function

```
function stopSelected(){
        var stop=document.getElementById('stops').value;
        alert(stop);
        var html="";
        $.ajax({
          type:"POST",
          url:"/DisplayRoute/findStopsRoutes",
          data:{
            stopToSearch:stop; 
          },
          success:function(resultedRoutes){
           alert(resultedRoutes[0]);
          },
          error: function(resultedRoutes){
            alert("error");
          }

        });
      }
```

The function shows alert when called without ajax. But when I include ajax it shows no alert.
my function on server side is as logs here.

```
'findStopsRoutes': function(req,res){
        console.log("here");

    }
```

I have similar code working at another place but it is not working here properly.
Please help me solve the issue.

Comment: check the url provided in ajax call..and instead of type post try get.

Comment: I have checked the url. If I enter the url directly it successfully calls the desired function

Comment: And get is also not working

Comment: Open your console, learn how to debug javascript

Comment: @A.Wolff I have checked the console.

Comment: @SSMA BUT then, this is wrong syntax: `data:{
            stopToSearch:stop; 
          }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try modifying the code from

```
data:{
        stopToSearch:stop; 
},
```

to

```
 data:{
      stopToSearch:stop
 },
```

and verify

Comment: Thanks!
I can not believe I missed it.